# Optional Match selected openSymbol with closeSymbol

Tags: regex

i need a regex pattern that will match starts with symbol `@` and will end with `&` .

e.g:
Match with

`Terminate@gdcomrad&` ---|> without space between @ and &

also match with

`Terminated@gdcomrad, endsubstr&` ---|> with space

also with

`Terminated` ---|> without @ and & .

optional only,
if found `@` find `&` to close

Comment: you're about to get hit with multiple down-votes if you don't edit your post and show something you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(.+?)(?:(@[^&]+&)|\b)
```

Try this See demo.Grab the captures.

http://regex101.com/r/pQ9bV3/24

Comment: it worked now and i get this result:
http://oi61.tinypic.com/2cehowk.jpg
the problem now was just the group i get 3groups and if its terminated only it goes to group3 which it should be on 1 ... also if i add text after & it added to match but for the groups its still correct

Comment: the group all are worked now @vks, thanks for that! but can i ask if why the word after Terminator(with space) and & still in match?

Comment: btw this pattern was the one works: ^(.*?)(?:(@[^&]+&)|\s).*$

Comment: @Elegiac try now.Fixed